# How to change one person's name in Messages?

Tags: messages

How do you change one person's name in a chat? I don't mean group chat, I mean just one person in this chat.

Answer (score 2):

Add the contact to your contacts, then edit their name in your contacts. The change is reflected in the Messages app.